# How to return a variable that is in JsonArray Request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I use JsonArrayRequest inside a method(function), that return number.I use function JsonArrayRequest when I need it.
 
But some issue: function return wrong number, in code below function have to return variable lastNumber, i.e last number of variable i. Sorry if my qustion stupid, couse I am new in java and android.
 Note, function return the lastNumber when it used a second time. I suggest that the program in first time  is not implement JsonArrayRequest.
I following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ .Any help appreciate!

```
public int lastNumber = 0;    
private int makeJsonObjectRequest(int startList,int endList) {
            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            i = startLsit;
                            while(i < endList) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();

                                  /***** TONS OF CODE  *****/

                                        movieList.add(movie);
                                    }

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                              i++;
                              lastNumber = i;
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
            return lastNumber
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use incorrect way. you must return lastNumber after the network back answer. so I suggest that define your function output 'void'. Then you must use Interface for network. I explain it by code. like below:

this is your interface:

```
 public interface JsonObjectListener {

        public void onDone(int lastNumber);

        public void onError(String error);
    }
```

in your function do it:

```
    private void makeJsonObjectRequest(int startList, int endList, JsonObjectListener listener) {
            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            i = startLsit;
                            while(i < endList) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();

                                  /***** TONS OF CODE  *****/

                                        movieList.add(movie);
                                    }

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                              i++;
                              lastNumber = i;
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            if(listener!=null)
                                listener.onDone(lastNumber);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       if (listener != null)
                            listener.onError(error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        }
```

Then when you want use it, call it like below:

```
makeJsonObjectRequest(your_startList, your_endList, new JsonObjectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(int lastNumber) {
                /// Do every thing you want with lastNumber
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do in below way:

Add method for fetching server response from server:

```
    public void makeWebServiceRequest(String tag, final String url, int method, JSONObject jPassedObject, final VolleyResponseListener listener){

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method,url,jPassedObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            CustomProgressbar.hideProgressBar();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        listener.onVolleySuccess(url, response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        try {
                            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                            if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                                // HTTP Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
                            }
                            CustomProgressbar.hideProgressBar();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        listener.onVolleyFailure(url);
                    }
                });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

}
```

Add interfece to pass data to any Activity/Fragment:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {

    void onVolleySuccess(String url, String serverResponse);
    void onVolleyFailure(String url);
}
```

How to call this method ?

```
  makeWebServiceRequest("Get Request", "URL HERE", Request.Method.GET, null, new VolleyResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVolleySuccess(String url, String serverResponse) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVolleyFailure(String url) {

        }
    });
```

**Note:** You should write your logic in your Activity/Fragment instead of common webservice calling code.

You would get your server response in `onVolleySuccess` override method.

Comment: @ElamanAitymbet, you are return value directly even if not calling api

Comment: @ElamanAitymbet, you should use above methods to manage common webservice call

Answer (score 1):

You want to use callback interface:

```
 public interface VolleyCallback{
        void onSuccess(int result);
    }  

// Method:
    public void getResult(VolleyCallback callback) {
                JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                i = startLsit;
                                while(i < endList) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                        Movie movie = new Movie();

                                        /***** TONS OF CODE  *****/

                                        movieList.add(movie);
                                    }

                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }
                            i++;
                            lastNumber = i;


                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  

                        callback.onSuccess(lastNumber);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
                callback.onSuccess(lastNumber);
                }
                });
            }}
```

Example code in activity:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getResult(new VolleyCallback(){
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(int result){
             ... //do stuff here result is your lastNumber 
         }
    });
}
```

I hope it work.